# Angular Firestore get nested collection `orderBy()` return empty array

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nested

#### Expected behavior

Getting from the firestore a nested collection `orderBy('seqNo', sortOrder)`

#### Actual behavior

I can easily fetch the data if I do:

```
getAll(collectioName: string) {
        const response: AngularFirestoreCollection<ID> = this.db.collection(collectioName);

        return response.snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(snaps => snapsCoverter(snaps))
            )
    }
```

but as soon as I do:

```
 getCollectionPaginated(collectioName: string, sortOrder: OrderByDirection, pagesize: number, pageNumber: number) {
        const response: AngularFirestoreCollection<ID> = this.db.collection(
            collectioName,
            ref => ref
                .orderBy('seqNo', sortOrder)
                .limit(pagesize)
                .startAfter(pageNumber * pagesize)
        );

        return response.snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(snaps => snapsCoverter(snaps))
            )
    }
```

It returns an `[]`

here's I invoke the method:

```
this.service.getCollectionPaginated(`courses/${id}/${nestedCollectionPath}`, "asc", 3, 0)
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

#### Information about the Issue

I am sure as hell the problem is here:

```
ref => ref
.orderBy('seqNo', sortOrder)
.limit(pagesize)
.startAfter(pageNumber * pagesize)
```

It works fine as long as I try to apply this logic to the main collection but it does't work on a nested one.

Could you please have a look?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`startAfter` doesn't take an integer page number.  In fact, Firestore paging doesn't use page numbers at all. In order to get another page of results, you have to first perform a limit query to get the first page, then pass a document reference or some other piece of identifying information about the last document from the first page to get the second page.

I suggest reading:

- [How to paginate to previous page using AngularFire, Firestore and Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074135/how-to-paginate-to-previous-page-using-angularfire-firestore-and-firebase)
- [Firestore + AngularFire2 pagination ( query items by range - .startAfter(lastVisible) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536684/firestore-angularfire2-pagination-query-items-by-range-startafterlastvis)

A web search will find other examples.

You might also want to read the [formal Firestore documentation on pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).  While the Angular APIs are slightly different, the concepts are exactly the same.

Comment: Hi @Doug,

First allow me to thank you for your answer! :)
Second pls accept my apologies because I should have been more specific: the problem is not `startAfter` but every query. In fact if we simply do

`const response: AngularFirestoreCollection<ID> = this.db.collection(
            collectioName,
            ref => ref
                .orderBy('seqNo', sortOrder)`
this will still return an `[]`. If you would like to test it by yourself I'll gladly make a repo for you.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Just made it work!

Longo story short the problem was in the way I was creating the relation: instead of loopinn trough an array of obj and store on the db each single obj inside the nested path, I was passing directly an `[{},{},{}]` and that's the reason why it was return an `[]` every time I was trying to make a db query such as `orderBy`, `where`, etc.

Now it works just fine and the pagination is awesome!

```
 getCollectionPaginated(collectioName: string, sortOrder: OrderByDirection, pagesize: number, pageNumber: number) {
        const response: AngularFirestoreCollection<ID> = this.db.collection(
            collectioName,
            ref => ref
                .orderBy('seqNo', sortOrder)
                .limit(pagesize)
                .startAfter(pageNumber * pagesize)
        );

        return response.snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(snaps => snapsCoverter(snaps))
            )
    }
```

Many Thanks!